# Conditionally show one child or another

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to create a component, that would render inner html, but on a click it would replace itself with editable version. I think something like this would work:

```
<field (onClick)="isEditModeOn = true;">
  <read-value>
      <h2>{{ someValue }}</h2>
  </read-only>
  <editable>
      <input type="text" [value]="someValue"/>
  </editable>
</field>
```

then in field.component I can get reference to those inner components:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
class Field {
  ...
  isEditModeOn = false;

  @ContentChild(ReadValueComponent) readValue: ReadValueComponent;
  @ContentChild(EditableComponent) editable: EditableComponent;
  ...

  onEdit() {
    if(isEditModeOn) {
      // render `editable`
    } else {
      // render `readValue`
    }
  }
}
```

But how to render one of those components in `field` template?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `*ngIf` for this:

```
<field (onClick)="isEditModeOn = true;">
    <read-value *ngIf="!isEditModeOn">
        <h2>{{ someValue }}</h2>
    </read-only>
    <editable *ngIf="isEditModeOn">
        <input type="text" [value]="someValue"/>
    </editable>
</field>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I could, but I would like to hide as many details from markup as I could, because I would like to reuse it in many places

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following form:

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<field (click)="isEditModeOn = !isEditModeOn;">

      <h2 *ngIf="!isEditModeOn">{{ someValue }}</h2>


      <input *ngIf="isEditModeOn" type="text" [value]="someValue"/>

</field>
```

**COMPONENT:**

```
 @Component({
      ...
    })
    class Field {
      ...
      isEditModeOn: boolean = false;

      ...

      @HostListener('click') onEdit() {
        if(isEditModeOn) {
          // render `editable`
        } else {
          // render `readValue`
        }
      }
    }
```